# Relative links using ~ symbol and slash

Tags: asp.net, url, hyperlink, relative-path

I saw some of the links in my ASP.NET site uses relative links but with ~ symbol. What does it do, and what are the advantages of using this?

```
href="~/jscript/forms.js"
```

Thanks.

Comment: See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) about Web application root operator

Answer (score 1):

It points root of the application.

`/` -> Root of the website

`~` -> Root of the application

Comment: ~ Root of asp/.net application only? or can this work in php like in joomla?

Comment: As far as I know it is just for ASP.NET and maybe C#. I didn't see it in other languages.